# How to get a union type from a property value in an object of objects?

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have an object:

```
const familyCars = {
  father: {
    make: "BMW",
    color: "white"
  },
  mother: {
    make "Toyota",
    color: "white"
  },
  son: {
    make: "Ford",
    color: "black"
  }
}
```

How to define a union type that will include all possible values of mark property for all family members: `"BMW" | "Toyota" | "Ford"`

Comment: Missing `:` after the second "make" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with [indexed access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) but it will also require to define your const with `as const` to prevent the values to be widen to `string`.

```
const familyCars = {
  father: {
    make: "BMW",
    color: "white"
  },
  mother: {
    make: "Toyota",
    color: "white"
  },
  son: {
    make: "Ford",
    color: "black"
  }
} as const

type FamilyCar = typeof familyCars;

type Maker = FamilyCar[keyof FamilyCar]['make']
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgQwLYEsA2BPAwggThGAXhgG8AoGeBKACwFNcAuUiymJBAazuYCIAhALIB1XgBpWlUGhBMYvAO40UUOr1YBfCZSQhaDZuTbsuPeQBUQGPQnGSY02XyUq1m7TAjhD9jtz4AYrIAJnbGjnK8AEZoCMCc6pQaZBowCASgkFBkZFAYAA50MAHI6Nh4RDB5hSBwVKiYOPgA3DnVRYKmuJUlDeW4ANrc1nW9ZU0AugMA5H500xNkAPRLbAB6APxAA)